# Python, Pandas to remove rows in Excel

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe

A spreadsheet to remove certain rows.

All the rows of its first column contains values started with “36” are to be removed, before saving to a new spreadsheet.

I use these codes (and need to split the columns afterwards in Excel). The example looks like this:

[image]

```
import xlwt
from xlrd import open_workbook

old_file = open_workbook('C:\\original.xlsx')
old_sheet = old_file.sheet_by_index(0)

new_file = xlwt.Workbook(encoding='utf-8', style_compression = 0)
new_sheet = new_file.add_sheet('Sheet1', cell_overwrite_ok = True)

contents = []

for row in range(old_sheet.nrows):
    a = str(old_sheet.cell(row,0).value)
    b = str(old_sheet.cell(row,1).value)

    if not a.startswith("36"):
        contents.append(a + "," + b)

for c, content in enumerate(contents):
    new_sheet.write(c, 0, content)

new_file.save('C:\\result.xls')
```

It’s not really sufficient so I want to learn the Pandas way doing so.

I tried something like df.drop(["3649"]) but it doesn’t work.

What’s the proper Pandas way to remove the rows? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need first [`read_excel`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_excel.html), then filter by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) with inverting mask by `~` with [`startswith`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.startswith.html) or [`contains`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.contains.html) (`^` is regex for start of string):

```
df = pd.read_excel('C:\\original.xlsx')

df = df[~df['Model'].astype(str).str.startswith('36')]
```

Alternative:

```
df = df[~df['Model'].astype(str).str.contains('^36')]

print (df)
   Model Country
0   1021  France
1   9644   India
2   9656   India
4   9687   China
6   9630   Spain
7   9666  Brasil
```

and last [`to_excel`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_excel.html):

```
df.to_excel('C:\\result.xls', index=False)
```

Comment: that's marvelous! by adding "index=False" to the df.to_excel line, I have it the same 2 columns. :) wish you a great weekend!

Comment: @MarkK - For you too, thank you. Greetings from Slovakia ;)